# How to Execute String formatted LINQ query in c# MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

```
     public ActionResult GenerateReport(FormCollection Form)
        {
            var type_id = Form["type_id"];           
            var Start_Date = Form["Start_Date"];

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();          
            sb.Append("db.contracts.Where(");
            if (!type_id.Equals(null))
            {
                sb.Append("a => a.type_id == type_id");
            }

            if (!Start_Date.Equals(null))
            {
                sb.Append("&& a => a.Start_Date == Start_Date");
            }
            sb.Append(");");
           //here I need to run the query!!
            return View(cm);
        }
```

How can i  execute this LINQ query in C#,
I just want to run the query and get the results..

Please help me...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I'm interested in why you are doing this?

Comment: After you edit: you really only want to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: @GertArnold, you can compile strings using the C# CodeDom classes at runtime, you dont have to emit things.. See GekaLlaur's answer for reference (too many edits, my answers irrelevant now too =()

Comment: @Dead.Rabit Yeah, all right, it's probably overkill either way unless this is some kind of special assignment. But I think the OP is only looking for a way to add predicates dynamically because the data source part of the query is know at run time (apparently). (BTW I removed my previous comment just before yours :) )

Comment: GertArnold I think you're right, though I have implemented this feature a few times @DimitarDimitrov though mostly in developer tools (internal log pages for example)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** this answer works with the original question content, how to execute this LINQ expression from a string:

```
var expression = @"( from a in Assignments
    where a.assignmentID == 1 && a.assignmentID == 4 )
    select new AssignmentModel
    {
        Title = a.Title,
        Description = a.Description
    }).ToList()";
```

though this answer should work with the generated string in the current question, only you would be injecting `db.contracts` rather than `Assignments` as I explain below.

---

The alternative to using the compilation classes as @GekaLlaur suggests is to compile the string into an Expression tree, which is possibly more appropriate here as you're compiling LINQ expressions.

The solution found in [this SO post (Chosen Solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-expression-tree) looks as though it should work out of the box for you, only using `var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<AssignmentModel>), "Assignments");` to describe your parameter. I would test it with your specific example but I don't already have the libraries ([linked here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)).

Comment: Just an added note, compiling code (any code) from strings at runtime is the definition of a security hole.. be very very careful to ensure that any parsed strings meet your expectations and can't run riot on the host PC.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Use a Predicate Builder instead!

Here is a great implementation from C# in a nutshell:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

The predicate builder uses a free library called linqkit:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Here is another SO question that addresses this topic and how the whole thing works
[How does PredicateBuilder work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490893/how-does-predicatebuilder-work)