# How to execute LINQ query at runtime c#

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

```
"((IEnumerable)sourceData).Cast().Select(ob => 
    new 
    { 
        SenderId = "Expo-HSE-01", 
        IssueId = ob.IncidentNo.Value, 
        IssuePointId = String.Join(",", ((IEnumerable)ob.TypeofIncident)
            .Cast()
            .Select(ip => ip.Value)), 
        IssueTypeId = "Issue-HSE-General", 
        ZoneId = ob.Location.LocationCode.Value 
    }"
```

Getting above query as string need to execute this at runtime.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794537/how-to-execute-string-formatted-linq-query-in-c-sharp-mvc3 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821365/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-equivalent-linq-expression-tree

Comment: Everything executes at runtime. What do you mean?

Comment: So what is the type of sourceData, and what would you like to get as result?

Comment: @itsme86 OP gets a string and needs to convert it into executable code.

Comment: @Santosh what have you tried so far? ([how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @itsme86 Need to execute linq query getting as string in c# 
And the query is dynamic , each time it changes based on the requirement.
Then the output from query will be dynamic , we wont be having any models for that since the aim is to make this code generic.

Comment: @itsme86 the source is of JObject type as of now.
and casting as dynamic to handle different types/objects of data from different sources

Comment: @nilsK Am working on generic solution to handle any source of data to destination expected payload(different names from src, mismatch in params count). 
So my idea is to send the destination required param as linq query from UI (tool) and execute that at run time.

Comment: @itsme86  got the solution from,
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399967/parse-string-into-a-linq-query)
Using CSharpScript namespace , now able to implement as expected. 
Thanks for your queries and suggestions Guy's.

Comment: @nilsK got the solution from,
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399967/parse-string-into-a-linq-query)
Using CSharpScript namespace , now able to implement as expected. 
Thanks for your queries and suggestions Guy's.

Answer (score 0):

[Parse string into a LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399967/parse-string-into-a-linq-query)

CSharpScripting able to execute the code getting as string.