# LINQ predicate in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to call method

```
 query.Range(item => item.Date, filter.Date);
```

and have method:

```
 public static IQueryable<T> Range<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T, DateTime> func, DateTime range)
    {
       return query.Where(item=> func(item) <= range); // <<-- Error "func(item)"
    }
```

**Error:** The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

How to use function?

Comment: Why not `query.Where(item => item.Date <= filter.Date)` ?

Comment: You are thinking too complex, think simple.

Comment: Generic type, cannot use Date.

Comment: Consider using PredicateBuilder for dynamic where conditions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490893/how-does-predicatebuilder-work

Comment: what are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
return query.Where(item => func(item) <= range);
```

Then lambda `item => func(item) <= range` is not simple lambda - its converted to `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`. When you are executing query, EF tries to convert such expressions into SQL code. Unfortunately it does not know how invocation of `func` should be represented in plain SQL. Thus you see this error. And you cannot use delegate invocations in expressions which you pass to EF.

Workaround: Instead of

```
query.Range(item => item.Date, filter.Date)
```

use simple (it's also more readable in this case)

```
query.Where(item => item.Date <= filter.Date)
```

---

UPDATE: You can to build date filter expression manually:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Range<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> func, DateTime range)
{            
    var predicate = 
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.LessThanOrEqual(func.Body, Expression.Constant(range)),
            func.Parameters.Single());

    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: It is common dll and used generic types

Comment: @Sequd updated answer. Now you can use this extension on any type to filter by date property

Comment: I just had a very similar case, which i did solve in the same manner, but i had to create manually a new parameter, replace the parameter of the func by the new one and provide it to the generated lambda, otherway i've got an "The parameter xxx was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression" exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more generic approch.

```
    public IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Where<T>(predicate).AsQueryable<T>();
    }
```

and call it:

```
query.Filter<MyClassIWantToFetch>(item => item.Date <= filter.Date)
```

and dont forget to change MyClassIWantToFetch to the type you want to get.