# C# Dictionary search predicate as method argument

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, where-clause, anonymous

I am trying to create a function whereby I can pass in a functor/predicate that can slot into a dictionary's 'Where' method.

(cardPool is the dictionary of type 'cardStats')
Pseudo of what I'd like to do:

```
void CardStats findCard(Predicate<CardStats> pred)
{
    return cardPool.Where(pred);
}
```

This code obviously wont work but is simply a rough example of the functionality I am looking for.
I have had no problems setting this up for lists, but for a Dictionary, its really got me stumped.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Edit:
Ahh sorry I should have mentioned more: Cardstats is the value, the key is of type int. I'd like to sift through the values (cardStats) and test their properties such as ID(int) or name(string).

Comment: Dictionaries have two generic type parameters (the key type and the value type). Your dictionary can't just have one type.

Comment: Well is `CardStats` the value type or the key type? It sounds like you may just want to use either the `Values` or `Keys` property, then use `Where` as normal...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so  its `Where` extension method takes a predicate of type `Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool>`.

You could implement your method like this:

```
void CardStats findCard(Func<int, CardStats, bool> pred)
{
    return cardPool.Where(kv => pred(kv.Key, kv.Value))
                   .Select(kv => kv.Value)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
CardStats stats = myCards.findCard((id, stats) => id == 7);
```

or

```
CardStats stats = myCards.findCard((id, stats) => stats.Name == "Ace of Clubs");
```

Note that using `Where` on a dictionary doesn't take advantage of the dictionary's quick lookup features and basically treats it as a linear collection of key-value pairs.

---

One more comment: I would suggest providing a method that returns an `IEnumerable` of found cards if there are several. Or you could provide one that does that, and one that just returns the first match:

```
void IEnumerable<CardStats> findCards(Func<int, CardStats, bool> pred)
{
    return cardPool.Where(kv => pred(kv.Key, kv.Value))
                   .Select(kv => kv.Value);
}

void CardStats findCard(Func<int, CardStats, bool> pred)
{
    return findCards(pred).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Ahh sorry I should have mentioned more:
Cardstats is the value, the key is of type int.
I'd like to sift through the values (cardStats) and test their properties such as ID(int) or name(string).

Comment: "key-value" is important to look for. Performance you need to consider in large dictionary.

Comment: You can also do cardPool.Where(pred).ToList() to get all the values matching the pred

Comment: @ChaturvediDewashish You can't directly pass a `Func<int, CardStats, bool>` to the `Where()` method because it expects a `Func<KeyValuePair<int, CardStats>, bool>`. I chose to use the former in the method signature because it allows writing lambdas like `(id, stat) => id == 5` instead of `kv => kv.Key == 5`, which is less clear in its intent.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks. Nice catch. Actually I had wrapped it as Expression<Func<CardStats, bool>>. It helped me build complex predicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490893/how-does-predicatebuilder-work

Comment: Thank you, JLRishe!
Just gave it a whirl and it does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use FirstOrDefault as the first statement because it will stop as soon it finds a matching element. another thing is that I will consider using something else than a dictionary - because when using it this way is abuse if its indexed purpose.

anyway, this is the code I will use:

```
public CardStats Find(Func<CardStats, bool> predicate)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, Roster> kvCard = cardPool.FirstOrDefault(kvp => predicate(kvp.Value));
    if (kvCard.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<int, Roster>)))
        return null;
    return kvCard.Value;
}
```

Comment: LINQ uses lazy evaluation, so it will  not go through the remainder of the collection after the first item is found if you use `.Where().Select().FirstOrDefault()`. `.FirstOrDefault(pred)` is a little more concise, but then you need a null check as you have here. You can use the `?.` operator to simplify your code a bit, but my approach allows implementing select-multi and select-single helpers without duplicating code.