# Iterable disjunction in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

Let's assume I have an `IQueryable` collection, and list of some strings.

I can build query this way:

```
foreach (var somestring in somestrings)
{
     collection = collection.Where(col=>col.Property.Contains(somestring);
}
```

which will produce following SQL query:

```
SELECT ...... FROM ..... WHERE 
(Property LIKE '%something1%') AND 
(Property LIKE '%something2%') AND 
(Property LIKE '%something3%')
```

Note, that WHERE clauses are connected with ANDs.

Is there way, to construct similar query, but connected with ORs ?

Comment: The performance of that query would be very bad, whether you use `AND` or `OR`. Instead of using LINQ you should consider using full text search queries and indexes. The current query will scan the entire table to find matches without any benefit from indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PredicateBuilder like [this](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). See SO for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490893/how-does-predicatebuilder-work).

Here you can connect queries with AND or OR.

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

[Sample taken from C# 7.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

I've used this successfully when implementing custom search fields

eg.

[red blue] -> searches for red AND blue

[red, blue] -> searches for red OR blue

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one query without looping using `Any`:

```
var result = collection
    .Where(col => somestrings
        .Any(s => col.Property.Contains(s)));
```

Or the same query with simplified syntax:

```
var result = collection
    .Where(col => somestrings
        .Any(col.Property.Contains));
```

Comment: Nice! But the performance will be *really* bad. That's one place where LINQ isn't appropriate. Unless it's LINQ to Elastic or another search engine

Comment: Not possible in LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: Does not fit best my situation - but this is really beatifull solution!